# Laravel View doesn't recognize my service provider

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a service provider for the first time, to pass some data to my project view but i get an error message : `Undefined variable: core`   Since i have already registred my new Service Provider in the config file correctly

```
 App\Providers\CoreServiceProvider::class
```

This is my CoreServiceProvider.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Core;

class CoreServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function($view){
            $core = Core::all();
            return $view->with('core', $core);
        });
    }
}
```

My index.blade.php

```
dd{{$core}}
```

Comment: That is strange.. what's inside Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are making a **Custom ServiceProvider** class it wont be loaded into the application.

You need to manually register those into **Application**.

You can register custom service provider under.  `providers` array of `config/app.php` file.

Comment: can you try to clear cache by running ```php artisan optimize:clear```

Comment: Yes its ok it was a cache problem